# With Echo and html/template how can I pass HTML to the template?

Tags: go, go-html-template

I'm using [Echo](https://echo.labstack.com) to build my first small Go web service and I went with the example they provide for using `html/template` for HTML page templates to simplify page management.

On one of the pages I'm collecting data from a backend API and wanted to display it in a table. I'm generating the HTML and then passing it into the template. Unfortunately `html/template` is encoding it as safe text rather than letting the HTML pass through.

I can see in the `html/template` docs how you could tell it the HTML is safe there but I'm not sure how to do that same thing inside Echo.

How do I make it so that HTML passed through `Render` is accepted as HTML instead of encoded?

Simplified versions of the go files and template:

`server.go`

```
package main

import (
  "io"
  "html/template"

  "github.com/labstack/echo"
  "github.com/labstack/echo/middleware"
  "github.com/labstack/gommon/log"
)

type Template struct {
  templates *template.Template
}
func (t *Template) Render(w io.Writer, name string, data interface{}, c echo.Context) error {
    return t.templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, name, data)
}

func main() {
  t := &Template{
    templates: template.Must(template.ParseGlob("views/*.html")),
  }

  e := echo.New()
  e.Logger.SetLevel(log.INFO)
  e.Use(middleware.Logger())

  e.Renderer = t

  e.GET("/", homePage)

  // HTTP server
  e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":1323"))
}
```

`pages.go`

```
package main

import (
  "github.com/labstack/echo"
)

func homePage(c echo.Context) error {
  return c.Render(http.StatusOK, "home", "<p>HTML Test</p>")
}
```

`views/home.html`

```
{{define "home"}}
{{template "head"}}
{{template "navbar"}}

{{.}}

{{template "foot"}}
{{end}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered [in the `html/template` package summary](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#hdr-Typed_Strings):

> By default, this package assumes that all pipelines produce a plain text string. It adds escaping pipeline stages necessary to correctly and safely embed that plain text string in the appropriate context.
>
> When a data value is not plain text, you can make sure it is not over-escaped by marking it with its type.

For example:

```
return c.Render(http.StatusOK, "home", template.HTML("<p>HTML Test</p>"))
```

Comment: Yeah, I saw the part about the escaping at the top.

I wasn't sure how the "marking" part worked; how does using `template.HTML("str")` return a "marked" string?

Comment: If you look at the [definition for `template. HTML`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#HTML), it's just a type based on `string`. By coercing a string to that type, you're telling the package it doesn't need to escape it.

Comment: Rad. Thanks. Still learning go and coming from mostly duck-typed languages I think I misunderstood how Types worked in this sense. That's pretty cool.